# GWT - get custom property from datasource datable

Tags: java, gwt, datatable, datasource, google-visualization

I am sending a  visualization.datasource.datatable.DataTable from the server side in my GWT app. I am setting a custom property.

```
 datatable.setCustomProperty("key","value");
```

i can see the property being set and the json returned has a

```
"table": {
    "rows":[....]
    "cols":[...]
    "p":{ "key":"value"}
}
```

but how do i retrieve it using an instance of visualization.client.datatable?
there is a

getProperty(row,col,name)

method, but now sure of its usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that a method to retrieve custom properties on data table is exposed.

You can check that in the [javadoc](http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/visualization/1.1/com/google/gwt/visualization/client/DataTable.html) of version 1.1

Though you can query your dataTable using JSNI. The javascript method to query custom property set on DataTable is available in its [javascript documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/reference.html). The GWT library is just a wrapper on the javascript library. So you can do something like given below:

```
private native void getProp(DataTable dataTable, String name) /*-{
    alert(dataTable.getTableProperty(name));
}-*/;
```